# Creating a RegEx to find a sentence with a parenthetical acronym (VBasic Word)

Tags: regex, vba, find, ms-word

I'm writing a script that scrubs a document to find acronyms in the format (USA).  As a processing tool I need to grab the entire sentence in which that parenthetical acronym appears.  Right now my code for finding the acronym is:

```
With oRange.Find
        .Text = "\([A-Z]{2,}\)"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWildcards = True
```

Combining this with a Do While .Execute I can comb the doc and find the acronyms, then using a string function I take the acronym out of the parentheses and put it in a table.  Is there a RegEx that I could use which would find any sentence an (USA) type acronym is in?  As an input you could use this paragraph.

Thank you very much.

edit:  I found the following Regex to try and make it work:

```
.Text = "[^.]*\([A-Z]{2,}\)[^.]*\."
```

But this is giving me an error, saying that the carrot can't be used in the Find function.

Comment: I'd try `[^.]*([\(][A-Z]{2,}[\)])[^.]*[\.]`, not sure `.Find` can handle Regex directly, so you may have to take a [look at this answer! ;)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11370773/4628637)

Comment: This regex gives me an error "Compile error: Expected: ) ".  I think the find is working correctly, I'm just not sure how to construct the Regex.

Comment: Can you post some examples? acronym sentence

Comment: @Nate : Did you manage to make it work? Please take the **[tour] (click the link)** so that you can see how SO works (votes, accepting answers, ...). Thx!

Comment: I was able to make it work with the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't managed to use that regular expression directly in the `.Find` method, so using Regex directly :

```
Sub AcronymFinder()
    Dim Para As Paragraph
    Set Para = ThisDocument.Paragraphs.First
    Dim ParaNext As Paragraph
    Dim oRange As Range
    Set oRange = Para.Range
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim ACrO As String

    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = ".*[^.]*([\(][A-Z]{2,}[\)])[^.]*[\.]"
    End With

    Do While Not Para Is Nothing
        Set ParaNext = Para.Next
        Set oRange = Para.Range
        'Debug.Print oRange.Text
        If regEx.test(oRange.Text) Then
            ACrO = CStr(regEx.Execute(oRange.Text)(0))
            'Debug.Print ACrO
            With oRange.Find
                .Text = ACrO
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindStop
                .Format = False
                .MatchCase = True
                .MatchWildcards = False
                .Execute
            End With
        Else
        End If
        Set Para = ParaNext
    Loop
End Sub
```

to use it, remember to add the reference :

```
Description: Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
FullPath: C:\windows\SysWOW64\vbscript.dll\3
Major.Minor: 5.5
Name: VBScript_RegExp_55
GUID: {3F4DACA7-160D-11D2-A8E9-00104B365C9F}
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex

```
[^046][!^046]*\([A-Z]{2,10}\)[!^046]*[^046]
```

when used in the `Find` dialog will find a sentence (bounded by full stops ^046).

Note that this regex returns a string with full stops on both ends, e.g.,

> . A three-letter acronym (TLA) was used.

Also note that I limited acronym length to 10 chars [A-Z]{2,10}; change the upper limit as needed.

Finally I observed that this DOES NOT find acronyms at the end of a sentence, e.g.

> I used a three-letter acronym (TLA).

The `[!^046]*` part of the regex does not appear to match a zero length string. To catch those cases you would need to do a second pass search with this:

```
[^046][!^046]*\([A-Z]{2,10}\)[^046]
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This Regex gives a compile error "Expected: end of statement".  Am I missing some sort of library or setting?  I'm working in Microsoft's VB editor inside word.

Comment: When I use `.Text = "[^046][!^046]*\([A-Z]{2,10}\)[!^046]*[^046]"` I do not get a compile error and `Find` captures sentences with acronyms.

Comment: That's because I'm an idiot and forgot the quotation marks!  Will try this later.

Comment: Additional limitations of this solution: (1) Since it looks for the period in the previous sentence, the regex won't find matches in sentence #1. (2) Acronyms at the beginning of a sentence are a special case (see the note about acronyms at the end of a sentence). (3) Didn't test the regex on sentences with multiple acronyms.

Comment: Thank you.  This is what I was looking for.