# Rename and save attachment from Outlook

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I'm trying to save an attachment using Outlook rules and rename it to a word found in the email message body.

The word is on the third populated line, after the colon.

I have a rule set to run this script.

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoNet(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "O:\EUROMKTG\Marketing Analytics Dept\Campaign 
Reporting\Campaign Dashboard\1. Exact Target (Salesforce Mrktg Cloud)"
 For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
      objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
      Set objAtt = Nothing
 Next
End Sub
```

[image: Email Body]

Comment: Is the 'word' you want to use in the main email, or does that contain (several) attached email(s) and you want the 3rd line from that/those?

Comment: In the main email. I recieve 1 email with 1 attachment. I want to save the attachment using the above VBA but would like to rename the attachment to be the word poulated in the main email. thanks

Comment: Can you post an example image of the email body?

Comment: added the email body picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this :

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoNet(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    saveFolder = "O:\EUROMKTG\Marketing Analytics Dept" & _
                    "\Campaign Reporting\Campaign Dashboard" & _
                    "\1. Exact Target (Salesforce Mrktg Cloud)"

    Dim JobTxtInMail As String
    JobTxtInMail = "Exported for - JobID:"
    Dim StrStart As Integer
    StrStart = InStr(1, _
                    itm.Body, _
                    JobTxtInMail, _
                    vbTextCompare) + Len(JobTxtInMail) + 1
    Dim JobNum As String
    JobNum = Trim(Mid(itm.Body, _
                    StrStart, _
                    InStr(StrStart + 1, itm.Body, Chr(13)) - StrStart - 1))

    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & JobNum & "__" & objAtt.DisplayName
        Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next objAtt
End Sub
```

You may have to tweak a bit the `+ 1` and `- 1`, respectively in `StrStart` and `JobNum`.

And to change the `objAtt.SaveAsFile` to fit the desired output!

Comment: Hi, thanks for this - i don't understand what it's doing though and it's pulling through the JobID and not the Type. Do you know anything about RegEx and using something like .Pattern = "(Exported Type\s*[:]+\s*(\w*)\s*)"?

Comment: @CameronR : Change `JobTxtInMail = "Exported for - JobID:"` to `JobTxtInMail = "Exported Type:"` will extract the type. What it does, it's finding the string `JobTxtInMail` inside the body of the mail, define the start (`StrStart`) of the part you want to extract and then find the end of the line to extract (`JobNum`) that part. yeah sure, you could do it with Regex to but I'd say it's heavy artillery if you are only looking for one information. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44018269/4628637) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43896112/4628637) if you want to try it with Regex! ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky to do without seeing some example emails but before you launch the `For Each objAtt..` loop you want to 'grab' the word. I'd be looking in `itm.Body`. If you use `Split` to break this up with Chr(13) - a carriage return you then just need to pick the 3rd 'populated' segment. You need confidence that the 3rd line is going to contain a valid filename etc. but see below for an **untested** idea how you might do it:

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoNet(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    Dim bodystring, sgmnt As String
    Dim sgmntcounter As Integer
    saveFolder = "O:\EUROMKTG\Marketing Analytics Dept\Campaign " _
    & "Reporting\Campaign Dashboard\1. Exact Target (Salesforce Mrktg Cloud)"

    bodystring = itm.Body
    bodysegments = Split(bodystring, Chr(13))

    For Each sgmnt In bodysegments
        If sgmnt <> "" Then sgmntcounter = sgmntcounter + 1
        If sgmntcounter = 3 Then Exit For
    Next

    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
         objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & sgmnt
         Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```