# How to replace Numbers in Parentheses with some calculations in MS Word

Tags: regex, vba, preg-replace, ms-word

I have a problem to replace some serial number such as [30] [31] [32]... to [31] [32] [33]... in MS word when I insert a new references in the middle of article. I have not found a solution way in GUI so I try to use VBA to do that replacement. I find a similar problem in stack overflow:

[MS Word Macro to increment all numbers in word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154503/ms-word-macro-to-increment-all-numbers-in-word-document)

However, this way is a bit inconvenient because it have to generate some replacement array in other place. Can I make that replacement with regex and some function in MS Word VBA like code below?

```
Sub replaceWithregExp()

Dim regExp As Object
Dim regx, S$, Strnew$
Set regExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With regExp
    .Pattern = "\[([0-9]{2})\]"
    .Global = True
End With
'How to do some calculations with $1?
Selection.Text = regExp.Replace(Selection.Text, "[$1]")
End Sub
```

But I don't know how to do some calculations with $1 in regExp? I have try use "[$1+1]" but it return [31+1] [32+1] [33+1]. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this is obvious, but I don't understand. Why not use the normal search and replace? Just start with the highest number and work your way down.

Comment: @Andreas  I want to find a more convenient way to solve this kind of problems, and then next I will not need to search and replace again and again and only need to change some code and click run :)

Comment: Ok. What about you do a regex match and manipulate the match then do a "replace" with oldstring and newstring?  I'm not sure regex replace works the way you want. Regex match on the other hand will work.

Comment: @Andreas I don't know how to limit the scope of each replacement because I am not familiar with the grammar of VBA. If the full text is replaced by every newstring every time it may lead to some repeated replacement. Wiktor Stribiżew  have given the solution way under and it work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to pass a callback function to the `RegExp.Replace`, so you have the only option: use `RegExp.execute` and process matches in a loop.

Here is an example code for your case (I took a shortcut since you only have the value to modify inside known delimiters, `[` and `]`.)

```
Sub replaceWithregExp()

Dim regExp As Object
Dim regx, S$, Strnew$
Set regExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With regExp
    .Pattern = "\[([0-9]{2})]"
    .Global = True
End With
'How to do some calculations with $1?
' Removing regExp.Replace(Selection.Text, "[$1]")
For Each m In regExp.Execute(Selection.Text)
    Selection.Text = Left(Selection.Text, m.FirstIndex+1) _
        & Replace(m.Value, m.Value, CStr(CInt(m.Submatches(0)) + 10)) _
        & Mid(Selection.Text, m.FirstIndex + Len(m.Value))
Next m

End Sub
```

Here,

- `Selection.Text = Left(Selection.Text, m.FirstIndex+1)` - Get what is before
- `& Replace(m.Value, m.Value, CStr(CInt(m.Submatches(0)) + 10))` - Add `10` to the captured number
- `& Mid(Selection.Text, m.FirstIndex + Len(m.Value))` - Append what is after the capture

Comment: Thank you Wiktor Stribiżew! Cool codes and it work preferly!

Comment: Have clicked. I am a new user of stackoverflow so is not familiar with that function yet. :P

Answer (score 1):

That should do the trick :

```
Sub IncrementWithRegex()
    Dim Para As Paragraph
    Set Para = ThisDocument.Paragraphs.First
    Dim ParaNext As Paragraph
    Dim oRange As Range
    Set oRange = Para.Range
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim regMatch As Variant
    Dim ACrO As String

    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "[\[]([0-9]{2})[\]]"
    End With

    Do While Not Para Is Nothing
        Set ParaNext = Para.Next
        Set oRange = Para.Range
        'Debug.Print oRange.Text
        If regEx.test(oRange.Text) Then
            For Each regMatch In regEx.Execute(oRange.Text)
                oRange.Text = _
                    Left(oRange.Text, _
                         InStr(1, oRange.Text, CStr(regMatch))) & _
                    CDbl(regMatch) + 1 & _
                    Right(oRange.Text, _
                          Len(CStr(regMatch)) + InStr(1, oRange.Text, CStr(regMatch)))
            Next regMatch
        Else
        End If
        Set Para = ParaNext
    Loop
End Sub
```

To use this, remember to add the reference :

```
Description: Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
FullPath: C:\windows\SysWOW64\vbscript.dll\3
Major.Minor: 5.5
Name:     VBScript_RegExp_55
GUID: {3F4DACA7-160D-11D2-A8E9-00104B365C9F}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple VBA macro you can use to achieve this :

```
Sub IncrementNumbers()

    Dim regExp As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim fullMatch As String
    Dim subMatch As Integer
    Dim replacement As String
    Const TMP_PREFIX As String = "$$$"

    Set regExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With regExp
        .Pattern = "\[([0-9]{2})\]"
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
    End With

    'Ensure selected text match our regex
    If regExp.test(Selection.Text) Then
        'Find all matches
        Set matches = regExp.Execute(Selection.Text)
        ' Start from last match
        For i = 0 To (matches.Count - 1)
            fullMatch = matches(i).Value
            subMatch = CInt(matches(i).SubMatches(0))
            'Increment by 1
            subMatch = subMatch + 1
            'Create replacement. Add a temporary prefix so we ensure [30] replaced with [31]
            'will not be replaced with [32] when [31] will be replaced
            replacement = "[" & TMP_PREFIX & subMatch & "]"
            'Replace full match with [subMatch]
            Selection.Text = Replace(Selection.Text, fullMatch, replacement)
        Next
    End If

    'Now replacements are complete, we have to remove replacement prefix
    Selection.Text = Replace(Selection.Text, TMP_PREFIX, "")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But this method may sometimes have a bit of problem. Because the reference literature serial number is not necessarily ascending in the article. For example sometimes I may quote a same reference literature at the beginning and end of the article.

Comment: Ok, I'll fix this in a few hours ;)